# Android getting GPS coordinate updates while device is in sleep (Screen is turned off)

Tags: java, android, gps

I have a problem. I want to get GPS coordinate updates while the device is in sleep mode (The user turned the screen off).

I'm currently using a service to get the GPS coordinates in a background task, but this service stops after a moment when the device is in sleep mode. How can I achieve to get continously the current GPS coordinates, as long as the service should run?

Why I need that? Its to check when the user reaches a certain place, to get a notification.

Answer (score 0):

A service must be able to do it.  Try the IntentService class instead of the Service class to create your own service.

Comment: Hmm I'm actually doing it like this: Starting the service, on the onstart() method I create my location listener, and in the onlocationchange() method, I let vibrating the phone. but after turning the screen off, it will vibrate let say 10 times or for a small amount of time but afterwards it stops.